# JS GUI framework on top of Django REST framework

Tags: javascript, framework, django, rest

I am sick of sending HTML from my Django application to the web browser. I think it is time for a change. I would like to send **data** to the client.

In other projects I used the [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Is there a JavaScript GUI library which can render pages with forms, inputs, tables, … from data received via Django REST framework?

Other solutions (which don't use the REST framework) are welcome, too.

Needed features:

- JS library to display pages, forms, inputs, …
- open source (not GPL)
- active development
- should get/post data via HTTP
- No HTML should be transferred via HTTP (or at least only few)
- Render HTML for PC (important) and mobile (nice to have) on the client

Answer (score 1):

I found this project which enables users to build applications using Django and Ember.js:

> Ember Django Adapter (EDA) enables users to build applications using Django REST Framework and Ember.js. The two packages work with REST APIs, but differ on certain JSON formatting and semantics. Fortunately, Ember Data (the library powering Ember.js models) provides an opportunity to write custom adapters to bridge these differences. EDA is one such adapter specifically designed to work with Django REST Framework.

See: http://dustinfarris.com/ember-django-adapter/